# A variance computation

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, additive-combinatorics

Can you help me compute a variance?

Let $(x_{i,j})_{(i,j)\in\mathbb{N}^2}$ be random variables with these two properties:

- for any $(i,j)\in\mathbb{N}, x_{i,j} = \overline{x_{j,i}}$
- for any $(i,j) \neq (l,k)$ or $(k,l)$ the variables $x_{i,j}$ and $x_{l,k}$ are independent.

Is there a formula which helps to compute the following variance, for even $k$, by interchanging $\mathbb{V}$ and $\Sigma$?

$$\mathbb{V}\left[ \sum_{i_1,\dots,i_k=1}^n x_{i_1,i_2} x_{i_2,i_3} \dots x_{i_{k-1},i_k} x_{i_k,i_1} \right]$$

It corresponds to the variance of the trace, $\mathbb{V}\left[\text{Tr}\left(X^k\right)\right]$ of a Hermitian random matrix $X=[x_{i,j}]_{(i,j)\in\{1,\dots,n\}^2}$.

I am looking for an extension of the formula for interchanging $\mathbb{V}$ and $\Sigma$ by decomposing the initial sum into many independent sums:

$$\mathbb{V}\left[ \sum_{i,j=1}^n x_{i,j} \ x_{j,i} \right] =  \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{V}\left[|x_{ii}|^2\right] + 2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} \mathbb{V}\left[ x_{i,j} \ x_{j,i} \right]$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why do you say this sum over $n$ products of $k$ matrix elements equals the trace of the matrix? isn't the trace the sum over $n$ diagonal matrix elements?

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker It seems to be $\mathrm{var} [\mathrm{Tr} ( X^k)]$

Answer (score 1):

For small $n$ you could just evaluate this by explicit calculation. For large $n$ there is a useful asymptotics:

Wigner [1] showed that, under quite general conditions on the distribution of the independent matrix elements, and setting their variance equal to unity, the large-$n$ asymptotics of the expectation value of $\text{Tr}\,(X^k)$ is given by a Catalan number,
$$E\,[\text{Tr}\,(X^k)]=\frac{n}{s+1}{{2s}\choose{s}}+O(n^{-1}),\;\;k=2s\;\;\text{even}.$$
The distribution of this trace satisfies a central-limit-theorem, converging for large $n$ to a Gaussian distribution with variance $1/\pi$. See for example [Central limit theorem for traces of large random symmetric matrices with independent matrix elements.](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/em/docs/boletim/vol291/v29-1-a2-1998.pdf)

[1] E.P. Wigner, [On the Distribution of the Roots of Certain Symmetric Matrices](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970008) (1958).